# How to apply a border radius to React table tfoot with 3 children while avoiding display block displacement?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React table where the code looks like this:

```
    <tfoot class="rounded-t-lg border bg-inpay-black-haze-100 text-sm" style="background:red">
      <tr>
        <td class="px-4 text-center"></td>
        <td class="px-4 text-center">1000</td>
        <td class="px-4 text-center"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

If I add display block to the tfoot the border radius will be applied but the 1000 in the  is going to move to the left and I do not want that. [without display block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z0CJ.png)
& [with display block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K4lW.png)

So basically I want 1000 in the same position (in the middle) but also apply the border radius. Is there a way to do this mantainin the same positions ?

PS: it was supposed to be border bottom not top

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `border-radius` to: `table`, `tfoot`,
or `tr`, only in `td`.

I would suggest making some changes inside your `tfoot`

First, remove those two unused `td`'s and add `colspan="3"` in the remain `td`.

```html
<tr>
  <td class="px-4 text-center">1000</td>
</tr>
```

Then, remove the `rounded-b-lg` class from the `tfoot` and added it to the `td`.

You can check a simple demo here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/QplVcNFj9y?layout=horizontal